# When one kid runs into another and they bump heads, why is the slowest mover in most pain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation

In my experience, if one kid runs really fast and accidentally bumps into a second kid who's standing still, and they bump heads, the kid who was 'standing still' (relative to earth) always seems to be impacted heavily (more 'damage received'), while the 'runner' doesn't suffer much physical damage at all. *This suggests that both 'objects' in a collision scenario seem to 'experience' the same event in different ways while relativity tells us the point of view of both objects is equivalent - they are both equally valid ways of analysing the event.*

So: **shouldn't both kids feel the same impulse and be about 'equally damaged'?** Since movement is relative, we might just as well view the situation from the point of view of the running kid (rather than the point of view of the kid standing still), and we then see the kid who's standing still approach us equally fast and bump heads in the exact same way. Looking at it this way, the kid standing still hit the runner in the head, so the runner should receive more physical damage. Since both points of view are equally valid, the only solution is that both should feel the exact same impulse (= equal 'damage').

Of course the details of any specific collision are a complex issue, but there is a trend here, a large discrepancy in 'favour' of the runner, that is not explained by merely calling upon differences in built, strength, ... Equivalent kids experiencing such a scenario where one kid just stands there while the other smashes into him at top speed result in the runner pretty much running through the stationary kid and hardly noticing, while the stationary kid is knocked out and receives much more physical damage. It's never the other way around.

So why do we notice a difference in practice?

(I guess we see the same effect in, for example, a soccer player performing a header: If another player shoots really hard and the ball hits another player's head, it hurts badly if that player is standing passively - even if the player is massive and strong - and a lot less if the other player actively moves towards the ball - even if the player is a relatively 'weak' person, and even though the speed with which both objects are moving towards each other is even greater when one moves actively towards an approaching object.)

Comment: Why the downvote? How is this a bad question?

Comment: Only the person who downvoted you can say why they did so, but you're asking about pain, which isn't really a matter of physics. If you could frame the question in terms of something like force or impulse instead, then it would be much better for this site.

Comment: I'm not asking about pain, I'm asking about why there seems to be a difference in two object 'experiencing' the same collision in very different ways while physics dictates they should be equivalent

Comment: Yes, but the way you have chosen to characterize the experience is in terms of pain. That's what I mean when I say you're asking about pain. If you edit the question not to mention pain at all, and instead characterize the difference of the experience in terms of some measurable physical quantity, then it would be much better.

Comment: Tried modifying the question to do that, is this better? The mention of kids and pain is the most intuitive way of asking the question I think. Experiencing such a collision is why I wondered about this in the first place :-)

Comment: That helps. Anyway, if you frame it in terms of impulse, it would help even more if you can find some evidence that the impulses experienced actually _are_ different.

Comment: Voting to close as each persons experience of the collision depends on factors beyond the scope of simple physics.  Stance, individual mass, height, weight, position, sensitivity, the distribution of forces in each body.  This is far to broad a problem.

Comment: That's the crux of my question, I don't think they are different. But aside from people having a different pain threshold, invariably the person moving slowest relative to earth has the most pain so what factor accounts for this difference? I take it most people on this site are smart enough to mentally translate the word 'pain' in terms of impact? :-)

Comment: @StephenG I would agree if  the outcome wouldn't be the same every time. Even with all these factors in play, the one moving fastest 'wins' in terms of suffering less. Seems to me there should be a fundamental explanation for why there isn't a 50/50 chance of either person being impacted most.

Comment: You are making the claim that one suffers more than the other, but I don't think we can treat that as a known fact.  This problem has no general solution and it's outside the bound of simple physics.  It's as much about medical issues as anything else.

Comment: I'm not talking about one kid being a crybaby and another a tough guy. I'm talking about two equivalent 'objects' colliding and the one at 'rest' suffering major trauma and the other not feeling a thing. This is not about the subjective experience of pain, it's about difference in physical effects on equivalent bodies in response to the exact same (equally powerful, same direction, but opposite signs) impulse. Maybe I'm failing to state my point. The medical side is completely irrelevant. A specific collision's details are way too complex to actually calculate, it's the trend I'm asking about.

Comment: -1. You seem to be basing your case on anecdotal evidence. Where is the evidence? Also, I am not convinced this is a physics question - you appear to agree that there is no physics reason for the effect. If the moving person is able to prepare for the collision while the stationary person is unaware of it until too late, that is a human factor and circumstantial - there's no reason why it couldn't be the other way round.

Comment: I think that it is interesting that we see so many action movies in which the hero (or the villain) head-butts his opponent with a head-against-head slam, and it's always the opponent that falls back stunned but people never seem to question why, from a physics standpoint, that that should be so.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to phrase the question clearly and coming up with an alternative example I might have stumbled upon a possible solution: bracing for impact. The active mover has a lot more muscle tension throughout his body and is better prepared to withstand the effects of a collision.

The soccer example is the exact same thing since an unwitting target probably has a more relaxed body than a player with rigid muscles actively trying to purposefully collide with an approaching ball as hard as he can.

Comment: This could work the other way round just as well. If the mover is unaware of the impending collision while the stationary person is prepared, the mover will be more likely to suffer an injury.

Comment: @sammygerbil And indeed this is the case in events like car crashes I believe: people who are asleep at the moment of impact (passengers!) tend to suffer less from whiplash injuries I think.